# Повороты персонажа с помощью нажатия клавиш

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр

Реализовал логику поворотов персонажа при нажатии клавиш: <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>. Но есть проблема, т.к. привязался к градусам, то при нахождении в позиции Up и необходимости сделать поворот Left, получается угол `270` градусов, что есть не естественным для пользователя. Подскажите, как решить этот вопрос? Код ниже.

```
document.onkeydown = function (event){
if (event.key == 'ArrowRight'){
    Player.direction.transform = 0;
};
if (event.key == 'ArrowLeft') {
    Player.direction.transform = 180;
};
if (event.key == 'ArrowDown'){
    Player.direction.transform = 90;
};
if (event.key == 'ArrowUp'){
    Player.direction.transform = -90;
};
    Player.renderPosition(htmlPlayer,Player);
};
```

---

Весь код:

```
<div id="dot" style="
    position: fixed; 
    border-radius: 50%; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover; 
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: transform .3s;
    -webkit-transition: transform .3s;
    -moz-transition: transform .3s;
    -o-transition: transform .3s;">
</div>

var htmlPlayer = $('#dot');
var GameMap = {
    width: $(window).width(),
    height: $(window).height()
};
var Player = {
    sizes: {
        width: 36,
        height: 36
    },
    position: {
        top: 0,
        left: 0
    },
    direction: {
        transform: 0
    },
    speed: 1.5,
    backgroundImage: 'img/player.png',
    setPosition: function(pos){
        switch(pos){
            case 'top':
                this.position.top = 0;
                this.position.left = GameMap.width / 2 - (this.sizes.width/2);
            break

            case 'left':
                this.position.left = 0;
                this.position.top = GameMap.height / 2 - (this.sizes.height/2);
            break

            case 'center':
                this.position.top = GameMap.height / 2 - (this.sizes.height/2);
                this.position.left = GameMap.width / 2 - (this.sizes.width/2);
            break

            case 'bottom':
                this.position.top = GameMap.height - (this.sizes.height);
                this.position.left = GameMap.width / 2 - (this.sizes.width/2);
            break

            case 'right':
                this.position.top = GameMap.height / 2 - (this.sizes.height/2);
                this.position.left = GameMap.width - (this.sizes.width);
            break
        }
    },
    renderPosition: function(elm,Player){
        elm.css({
            left: Player.position.left + 'px',
            top: Player.position.top + 'px',
            width: Player.sizes.width + 'px',
            height: Player.sizes.height + 'px',
            transform: 'rotate' + '('+ Player.direction.transform + 'deg)',
            'background-image': 'url('+ Player.backgroundImage +')',
        });
    }
};
Player.setPosition('center');
Player.renderPosition(htmlPlayer,Player);
document.onkeydown = function (event){

    if (event.keyCode) {
        Player.backgroundImage = 'img/player.gif';
    }


    if (event.keyCode == 37){
        if(Player.position.left <= 0){
            Player.position.left = 0;
        }else{
            Player.position.left-=Player.speed;
        }
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 38){
        if(Player.position.top <= 0){
            Player.position.top = 0;
        }else{
            Player.position.top-=Player.speed;
        }
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 39){
        if(Player.position.left >= GameMap.width-Player.sizes.width){
            Player.position.left = GameMap.width-Player.sizes.width;
        }else{
            Player.position.left+=Player.speed;
        }
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 40){
        if (Player.position.top >= GameMap.height-Player.sizes.height) {
            Player.position.top = GameMap.height-Player.sizes.height;
        }else{
            Player.position.top+=Player.speed;
        }
    }

    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
        Player.direction.transform = 180;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 38){
        Player.direction.transform = -90;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 39){
        Player.direction.transform = 0;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 40){
        Player.direction.transform = 90;
    }

    Player.renderPosition(htmlPlayer,Player);
    console.log(Player.direction.transform);
};
document.onkeyup = function(evt){
  if (event.keyCode) {
    Player.backgroundImage = 'img/player.png';      
  }

 Player.renderPosition(htmlPlayer,Player);
 };
});
```

Интересует момент с поворотами. При той логике, что задал, с положения `(event.keyCode == 37)` в положение `(event.keyCode == 38)` будет поворот в 270 градусов. Подскажите варианты решения?

---

```js
var htmlPlayer = $('#dot');
var GameMap = {
  width: $(window).width(),
  height: $(window).height()
};
var Player = {
  sizes: {
    width: 36,
    height: 36
  },
  position: {
    top: 0,
    left: 0
  },
  direction: {
    transform: 0
  },
  speed: 1.5,
  backgroundImage: 'img/player.png',
  setPosition: function(pos) {
    switch (pos) {
      case 'top':
        this.position.top = 0;
        this.position.left = GameMap.width / 2 - (this.sizes.width / 2);
        break

      case 'left':
        this.position.left = 0;
        this.position.top = GameMap.height / 2 - (this.sizes.height / 2);
        break

      case 'center':
        this.position.top = GameMap.height / 2 - (this.sizes.height / 2);
        this.position.left = GameMap.width / 2 - (this.sizes.width / 2);
        break

      case 'bottom':
        this.position.top = GameMap.height - (this.sizes.height);
        this.position.left = GameMap.width / 2 - (this.sizes.width / 2);
        break

      case 'right':
        this.position.top = GameMap.height / 2 - (this.sizes.height / 2);
        this.position.left = GameMap.width - (this.sizes.width);
        break
    }
  },
  renderPosition: function(elm, Player) {
    elm.css({
      left: Player.position.left + 'px',
      top: Player.position.top + 'px',
      width: Player.sizes.width + 'px',
      height: Player.sizes.height + 'px',
      transform: 'rotate' + '(' + Player.direction.transform + 'deg)',
      'background-image': 'url(' + Player.backgroundImage + ')',
    });
  }
};
Player.setPosition('center');
Player.renderPosition(htmlPlayer, Player);
document.onkeydown = function(event) {

  if (event.keyCode) {
    Player.backgroundImage = 'img/player.gif';
  }


  if (event.keyCode == 37) {
    if (Player.position.left <= 0) {
      Player.position.left = 0;
    } else {
      Player.position.left -= Player.speed;
    }
  }
  if (event.keyCode == 38) {
    if (Player.position.top <= 0) {
      Player.position.top = 0;
    } else {
      Player.position.top -= Player.speed;
    }
  }
  if (event.keyCode == 39) {
    if (Player.position.left >= GameMap.width - Player.sizes.width) {
      Player.position.left = GameMap.width - Player.sizes.width;
    } else {
      Player.position.left += Player.speed;
    }
  }
  if (event.keyCode == 40) {
    if (Player.position.top >= GameMap.height - Player.sizes.height) {
      Player.position.top = GameMap.height - Player.sizes.height;
    } else {
      Player.position.top += Player.speed;
    }
  }

  if (event.keyCode == 37) {
    Player.direction.transform = 180;
  }
  if (event.keyCode == 38) {
    Player.direction.transform = -90;
  }
  if (event.keyCode == 39) {
    Player.direction.transform = 0;
  }
  if (event.keyCode == 40) {
    Player.direction.transform = 90;
  }

  Player.renderPosition(htmlPlayer, Player);
  console.log(Player.direction.transform);
};
document.onkeyup = function(evt) {
if (event.keyCode) {
  Player.backgroundImage = 'img/player.png';
}

Player.renderPosition(htmlPlayer, Player);
};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dot" style="
     position: fixed; 
     border-radius: 50%; 
     -webkit-background-size: cover; 
     background-size: cover;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     transition: transform .3s;
     -webkit-transition: transform .3s;
     -moz-transition: transform .3s;
     -o-transition: transform .3s;">
</div>
```

(Полная картина)

Интересует момент с поворотами. При той логике, что задал, с положения (event.keyCode == 37) в положение (event.keyCode == 38) будет поворот в 270градусов. Подскажите варианты решения?

Comment: Можете уточнить в вопросе, чем вам конкретно мешает угол в 270 градусов?

Comment: Это не естественно, что в игре что в жизни всегда будешь делать/ожидать 90 или 180 градусов. Если я нахожусь в позиции Up, то я хочу повернуть на 90 градусов влево, а не на 270.

Comment: Естественность понятие относительное и индивидуальное. Мне, например, -90 непривычно )) В любом случае, опишите пожалуйста это уточнение в вопросе и добавьте, простая замена `if a == 270 then a = -90` вам подойдет, и если нет, то почему, какие доп.условия?

Comment: Положение Up (-90) нажимаю Right = 0                                             
Положение Right (0) нажимаю Down = 90                                       Положение Down (90) нажимаю Left = 180                                     
Положение Left (180) нажимаю Up = -90 (Идет разворот с углом в 270)

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему движок за кадром производит интерполяцию угла. При переходе между 0° и 90° всё работает нормально потому что интерполяция будет по кратчайшему пути. А вот при переходе через 360° так не работает потому что из 350 к 10 кратчайший путь будет через повернуть на +20°, а не на -340°.
Как одно из решений можно находить ближайший угол из соседних витков (-90°, -90° + 360° и -90° - 360°). В этом случае нужно учитывать изначальное направление.

```
var directions = {
    ArrowRight: 0,
    ArrowDown: 90,
    ArrowLeft: 180,
    ArrowUp: -90
};

document.onkeydown = function (event) {
    if (event.key in angles) {
        var targetAngle = directions[event.key];
        var delta = targetAngle - Player.direction;
        Player.direction.transform = Player.direction + delta;
    }
}
```

Но здесь появляется нюанс - теперь положение игрока может принимать значения больше 180° и меньше -90°. Чтобы это учесть, нужно при вычислении `delta` вычесть количество полных оборотов:

```
document.onkeydown = function (event) {
    if (event.key in angles) {
        // Вычитаем количество целых оборотов
        var normPlayerDirection = (Player.direction + 90) % 360 - 90;
        var targetAngle = directions[event.key];
        // Считаем угол, на который нужно повернуть объект
        var delta = targetAngle - normPlayerDirection;
        Player.direction.transform = Player.direction + delta;
        Player.renderPosition(htmlPlayer, Player);
    }
}
```

Но это решение далеко от наилучшего. Если вращать достаточно долго, то можно прийти к значениям, где абсолютный угол будет иметь очень высокие значения и погрешность вычислений чисел с плавающей точкой будет заметно. Чтобы этого избежать нужно посмотреть на то, как реализовано вращение в движке и выбрать более подходящие функции для изменения угла.

Comment: Спасибо:) Посмотрите, пожалуйста, ниже весь движок.